# block other actors with queuing requests in akka while processing current message

Tags: java, akka

I have an actor with two types of messages, one for inserting to mysql and the other for inserting to redis. I wonder how block that redis actor with queuing the messages in that actor related to inserting in redis, while the mysql actor is processing.

```
@Override
public Receive createReceive() {
    return receiveBuilder()
            .match(RedisMessage.class, message -> {
                try {
                    accountService.saveBusinessAccountRedis(message.redisBusinessAccount);
                    getSender().tell(OK, getSelf());
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    //getSender().tell(new Status.Failure(e), getSelf());
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    //createRedisUser(idMessage.uid);
                    getSender().tell(NOK, getSelf());
                }

            }).match(MySqlMessage.class, message -> {
                try {
                    accountService.saveBusinessAccount();
                    //ToDo: test for queuing another actor! remove!! :)
                    Thread.sleep(300);
                    getSender().tell(OK, getSelf());
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    getSender().tell(NOK, getSelf());
                }

            }).build();
}


@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
public static class RedisMessage {
    private final RedisBusinessAccount redisBusinessAccount;
}

@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
public static class MySqlMessage {
    private final BusinessAccount businessAccount;
}
```

Comment: you want only one match block to be executed at a time ?

Comment: the time MySqlMessage is processing, the RedisMessages should be queued without executing, and after MySqlMessage is processed, the RedisMessages in queue should be processed. Note that there is a scheduler for MySqlMessage to be proceed every 5 minutes.Somehow one message at a time!

Comment: one message of different types at a time :)

Comment: have a look at https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/mailboxes.html, you can choose a blocking Mailbox or maybe create your own

Comment: Your question isn't clear. If you are trying to make sure that only one type of message is processed at a time: Akka does that automatically: only one message is processed from the mailbox at a time  (per actor). On the other hand, if you need to "pause" Redis messages until you get some async reply back from MySql (not shown above) then see Arnout's answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So what you want is you want to avoid processing `RedisMessage`s while you haven't yet received the response of the action triggered by `MySqlMessage`, right?

Do you want to be able to process multiple `MySqlMessage`s in the same actor? I suspect you do not.

I would suggest using `become` and 'stashing'. When processing a `MySqlMessage`, use `become` to move the actor to a state where it is 'waiting for the `MySql` result'. In that state, when you receive additional `MySqlMessage` or `RedisMessage`, you `stash(msg)` them. When you receive the `OK` or `NOK` from the MySQL call, you `unstashAll()` and use `become` to go back to the 'normal' state where you can start processing any (stashed or new) commands again.

Does that make sense?